Using perl single liner, how to remove " around all column names in first row from a file
Using perl single liner, how to remove " around all column names in first row from a file.
Unable to delete double-quotes around column names only.
Input file
"FNAME","LNAME"
"A1B1","XYZ"
"A1B2","X12"

Output file without double-quotes around column names.
FNAME,LNAME
"A1B1","XYZ"
"A1B2","X12"


perl -pe '$.>1||s/"//g' input >output but sed is shorter: sed 1s/\"//g input >output

@jhnc That should perhaps be an answer instead of a comment.

Is it possible that your column names have escaped quotes in them?

@TLP as you point out, it is brittle - it'll work in absence of complications like escaped quotes or escaped newlines but not if input is actually full-blown CSV

Text::CSV_XS doesn't use quotes unless "necessary", so it will remove the quotes you want removed (and more).
perl -e'
   use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
   my $rows = csv( in => \*ARGV );
   csv( in => $rows, out => \*STDOUT );
' file.csv

Output:
FNAME,LNAME
A1B1,XYZ
A1B2,X12


OP actually says 4 times in his question that he only wants quotes removed from the first row.

Thank you @jhnc both perl and sed what you suggested did the trick and that's what I was looking for exactly.

@TLP, They said they didn't want the remaining quotes removed once, not four times. And I believe they want to keep the remaining quotes since there could be commas or newlines in the data. My solution will keep the quotes in those situations. My answer stands.

@ikegami In the title: how to remove " around all column names in first row, first line how to remove " around all column names in first row, second line Unable to delete double-quotes around column names only, last line Output file without double-quotes around column names. That's 4 times. God knows why you would want to remove quotes only from one row, but that's literally what he asked for.

@TLP, Read again. Only one of those four passages forbids removing the non-header quotes, contrary to your repeated incorrect claim. And even the OP had forbidden it four times, it wouldn't change anything.

@TLP, Re "God knows why you would want to remove quotes only from one row", As I mentioned above, probably because they know it's safe to remove those, but can't guarantee the safety of removing the others. Under that conclusion/assumption, it's ok to remove the other quotes too when safe to do so. Thus making my answer a valid solution. It's up to the OP to judge whether my assumption is correct or not.

@TLP I agree with you on "God knows why you would want to remove quotes only from one row", but it's customer requirement, not sure which of their downstream system need a file like this.

@Srinivasa Again you gave feedback to this issue without actually clarifying that this is your need. :) Am I correct, or is ikegami's answer satisfactory? Do you want quotes removed ONLY from the first row (column names), or from ALL rows?

@ikegami I am not disagreeing your solution is probably the best, I'm just saying it's not what OP asked for. Is there a way to enforce this behaviour with the Text::CSV module?

Re "I'm just saying it's not what OP asked for.", duh. I made that clear in the answer itself. Twice.

@TLP Yes I want quotes removed ONLY from the first row (column names), your solution did what customer want.
